# $_SESSION Error array is not printing

Tags: php, session, authentication

This is part of my login page, everything used to work I'm not sure if i changed something that caused an error. When printing the $_SESSION it says array but when i try to print $_SESSION['user'] like i saved the data in the code below it will not work???

```
require("includes/connection.php");
echo $_SESSION;
echo $_SESSION['user'];
echo ' ';
if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
{}
```

login page info, when i print the row is shows the array but when i change the page destination and try to print above the session is not printing anything.

```
unset($row['salt']);
unset($row['password']);
echo $row['username'];
$_SESSION['user'] = $row;
```

Comment: start the session http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php and check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Also it would be better to use print_r() to see the content of your variable instead of echo

Comment: Please add print_r() as @codeHeart suggests. Just where you have "echo $_SESSION;" add "print_r($_SESSION);".

Comment: session_start is already in my includes/connection.php

Comment: Its not echo $_SESSION; u can't print array as echo remove this line

Answer (score 0):

add this in first line;

```
ob_start();
session_start();
```

Comment: Does not work, i tried adding it to both the login page and at the beginning of my linked page after login.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `session_start();` at the top and `$_SESSION` is an array, you cant use `echo`, so you need to use `print_r($_SESSION);`